# Unable to delete Mongoose Document using Mongoose Middleware

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using Typescript + Mongoose + GraphQL which has following design

- User

  - Tasks

    - Comments

I am trying to write a mongoose middleware that will help me delete comments relating to a particular task if I were to delete a specific task

Presently, I am able to remove the specific task by calling findByIdAndRemove, however, my mongoose middleware isn't working as it is not 'cascading' to delete those comments related to the specific task I have deleted

Can someone help point out where I went wrong? Thanks

Below are my models

**Task**

```
import { Document, Schema, model, Types } from "mongoose";

const taskSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    completed: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
      required: true,
    },
    comments: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment",
      },
    ],
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

interface ITaskSchema extends Document {
  name: string;
  completed: boolean;
  comments: Types.Array<Object>;
  user: Types.ObjectId;
}

taskSchema.pre<ITaskSchema>("remove", function (next) {
  const Comment = model("Comment");
  Comment.remove({ _id: { $in: this.comments } }).then(() => next());
});

const Task = model<ITaskSchema>("Task", taskSchema);

export default Task;
```

**Comment**

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const commentSchema = new Schema(
  {
    review: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    task: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Task",
    },
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Comment = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);

export default Comment;
```

User

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";

import hobbySchema from "./Hobby";

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
    },
    hobbies: [hobbySchema],
    tasks: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Task",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

export default User;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove), `findByIdAndRemove` just trigger `findOneAndRemove()` middleware so you need to change your middleware to `findOneAndRemove`. But `findOneAndRemove` is **query middleware** so `this` in the middleware function refer to the query, not the document. To make it work, you need to make some change:

1. Use `findOneAndRemove` middleware.
2. Use `post` instead of `pre` because with `pre`, you can't get the doc.
3. Pass one more parameter that refer to the doc to the function.

The final code will look like:

```
taskSchema.post<ITaskSchema>("findOneAndRemove", function (task, next) {
  const Comment = model("Comment");
  Comment.remove({ _id: { $in: task.comments } }).then(() => next());
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cuong Le Ngoc! It works perfectly. Mind if I expand on the topic a little. The script works perfectly to delete task and comments specific to the task. I realize however in my User collection, i still have an array of taskIds under my user.tasks. Can i use the same middleware to reach 'up' to the User model to pull out those obseleted taskIds? I have added in the User model in case you need to take a look. Thanks very much

Comment: Yes, you can do it with `User.updateMany({tasks: task._id}, {$pull: {tasks: task._id}})`

Answer (score 0):

Credits and many thanks to Cuong Le Ngoc, it can work perfectly now! Below is the final mongoose middleware code

```
taskSchema.post<ITaskSchema>("findOneAndRemove", async function (task, next) {
  const Comment = model("Comment");
  const User = model("User");
  await User.updateMany({ tasks: task._id }, { $pull: { tasks: task._id } });
  await Comment.remove({ _id: { $in: task.comments } });
  next();
});
```